# How to bind new server binding while server active

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal

How i can let the OS assign available ports to new bindings in Indy server while the server is active ?

```
  IdUDPServer.Active := True;

  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    IdUDPServer.Bindings.add;
  end;

  for I := 0 to IdUDPServer.Bindings.Count-1 do
  begin
    WriteLn(IdUDPServer.Bindings[I].Port);
  end;
```

Will print the following :

```
40371
0
0
0
0
0
```

I try this

```
var
  H : TIdSocketHandle; 
  ...
  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    H := IdUDPServer.Bindings.add;
    try
      H.Bind;
    except
      On E: Exception do
        WriteLn(e.Message);
    end;
  end; 
  ...
```

I got the following:

```
Socket Error # 9
Bad file number.
Socket Error # 9
Bad file number.
Socket Error # 9
Bad file number.
Socket Error # 9
Bad file number.
Socket Error # 9
Bad file number.
56554
0
0
0
0
0
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without deactivate and reactive the server ?

because i don't want to lose any active client while adding new binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, you can't add new listening ports to `TIdUDPServer` while it is already active <sup>1</sup>.  It is simply not designed to allow that (compared to `TIdTCPServer`, which is).  `TIdUDPServer`'s listening ports are opened only when its `Active` property is toggled from False to True.

<sup>1: well, you can call `Bindings.Add()` all you want, but the new bindings won't have any effect in `TIdUDPServer`.</sup>

When you call `Bindings.Add()`, it assigns the server's `DefaultPort` to the `Port` property of the new `TIdSocketHandle` object.  The `DefaultPort` is 0 by default.  But to actually open the `TIdSocketHandle.Port` to listen for packets requires `TIdUDPServer` to be deactivated first.

Calling `TIdSocketHandle.Bind()` updates the `TIdSocketHandle.Port` if accessful (thus allowing you to bind to port 0 to assign an available ephemeral port), but the way you are using `Bind()` does not work because you are not calling `TIdSocketHandle.AllocateSocket()` beforehand, so the `TIdSocketHandle.Handle` is not valid for `Bind()` to use.  But even if you did get `Bind()` to work, it still would not help you, because `TIdUDPServer` creates a separate listener thread for each `Binding` object only when the `Active` property is toggled to True, so any new `TIdSocketHandle` objects you add to the `Bindings` while the server is already active will not read packets to give to your `OnUDPRead` event handler.

So, if you want to modify the `Bindings` ports in `TIdUDPServer`, you must set `Active=False` first, then modify as needed, and then set `Active=True`.  I have added an enhancement request to Indy's issue tracker for you:

[#294: Update TIdUDPServer to allow updating Bindings while active](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/294)

Note that UDP is connection-less, so you won't "lose clients" like in TCP, unless your UDP clients are designed to stop sending packets to your server if its listening port(s) are reported by the OS as closed when the packets are sent.